# Update column in SQL table with values from another row in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns (name, record, un, svun, svrecord):

| Name | idrecord | un | svun | svrecord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | JD123 | johndoe | NULL | JM123 |
| Jane Doe | JaD123 | janedoe | NULL | OR123 |
| Olive Err | OR123 | oliverr | NULL | GH123 |

I'm trying to populate the `svun` column with the value from the `idrecord` column when the `svrecord` matches an `idrecord` from another row.

For instance, row #2 should update the `svun` column to `OR123` because the `svrecord` (OR123) matches the `idrecord` (OR123) from the table. Hope this makes sense.

I've started trying to come up with a query for this below but can't quite figure it out...I'm sure i'm missing a parameter to make this work or maybe an additional select statement...:

```
UPDATE table 
SET svun = idrecord 
WHERE (svrecord = idrecord)
```

Comment: Please include the expected output.

Comment: *"I have a table with 4 columns (name, record, un, svun)"*  Your sample data has **five** columns.

Comment: Don't copy data around. Such behavior typically leads to data inconsistency. Create a view, or have a computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at update joins here: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

You will see this example:

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t1.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```

Now, we need to apply this for your table:

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    t1.svun = t1.idrecord
FROM
    yourtable t1
JOIN
    yourtable t2
ON
    t1.svrecord = t2.idrecort
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial query will only update `svun = idrecord` where `svrecord = idrecord` in the same row.

`UPDATE table SET svun = idrecord WHERE (svrecord = idrecord)`

In order to update records based on values that match in different rows you'll have to use a self join

```
with new_results as ( 
 select a.Name, a.svun, a.idrecord
 from table a
 inner join table b
 where a.svrecord = b.idrecord 
)

update new_results set svun = idrecord where svun is null
```

I don't recommend running this code without testing, but this should get you started

Answer (score 1):

You could join the table to itself.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET a.svun = b.idrecord
FROM YourTable a 
INNER JOIN YourTable b
ON a.svrecord = b.idrecord
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update table1
SET table1.svun = table2.idrecord
FROM table table1
INNER JOIN table table2 
    ON table1.svrecord = table2.idrecord
```